# We're waiting in a BIG or LONG queue?

Tags: idioms, adjectives, idiom-request

What's the idiomatic adjective for the noun "**queue**"?

> I waited there in a very **long** queue.

or

> I waited there in a very **big** queue.

Or maybe something else?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89180/discussion-on-question-by-witty-loquacity-were-waiting-in-a-big-or-long-queue).

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but you should know that in American English we say "line". "queue" is British English. The choice of adjective is the same as in the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [this NGram query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+*+queue&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows, *long* is the right answer.

[image]

This doesn't tell you *why* or even *how to remember it*, but I agree with Andrew's answer that *long* tends to be used for one-dimensional objects and *big* and *large* for higher dimensions. An area can be long but not big; take the country [Chile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chile) as an example. It's long, and big when compared to my backyard but rather small next to its neighbour Argentina.

Comment: Excellent example of an NGram query not showing you anything at all about the actual colloquial usage. Besides, it doesn't actually represent the two phrases being asked about (though [this corrected query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=big+queue%2Clong+queue&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbig%20queue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20queue%3B%2Cc0) still produces the same misleading answer)

Answer (score 30):

A "queue" is, by definition, line-shaped, therefore it makes sense to define it by its *length* rather than its *size*.  So "a *long* queue".

In contrast, a "crowd" is kind of blob-shaped, so you would say "a *big/large* crowd".

Comment: +1, and note that this exact same explanation is valid for the AmEng variant of a BrEng queue, that is, a line.  The grocery store has long lines at the checkouts, it doesn't have big lines.

Answer (score 20):

I can't argue with the logic of previous answers, preferring 'Long'.

But, as a native English speaker, I have to say that 'a big queue' would raise no eyebrows.

Comment: I would add huge as well "the queue was HUGE"

Comment: "Massive" is another one I hear far more commonly than "big". Eg, "Sorry I'm late, there was a massive queue at Tesco's"

Comment: I would say if the queue/line was a single, mostly straight, line, you would only use "long", but if it snaked back onto itself, big or other such adjectives start to become more common.

Answer (score 12):

Either one is fine to my British ears. Because of the physical shape of queues, any big queue has to be long, so the words have equivalent meaning in this case.

Comment: "any big queue has to be long" - That is not necessarily true in countries (like the USA?) which don't understand the basic concept of queuing. In such places, big queues tend to circular, not linear.

Comment: There are no queues in the US for lines, at the theater, cinema,for tickets, etc. There is not even a short or long of it here.

Comment: I hear queue a lot in the California Bay Area these days to refer to lines.  I think because of the influence of the influx of people who grew up with British English - but I hear it from natives.

Comment: @alephzero You seem to be referring to a crowd of people waiting, not a queue. And Americans seem fine with queueing in my experience...

Answer (score 3):

Only "half-native" here but just today I used "big queue" and it certainly did not raise any eyebrows among the "full-natives" around me.

Additionally to the previous answers I'd say that "big" can be understood as a "category" containing "long" and other "shapes" of "big". Therefore you could always use the superordinate "big" to replace any of the "subordinate" and more specific forms of "big".

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the **context of the metric(s)** being considered(mostly implicitly).

When we consider something in terms of only its **length** and **not width**, we use `long`.

For example:

- Nile river is 6695 km `long`. It is the **longest**  river on the planet earth.
- Mount Everest is 8848m `high` or 8848m **long**.

When we consider something in terms of its **width**, we use words such as **"big"**

For example:

- Nile river covers a **big** area of approx. 14000 sq km.
- The **biggest** continent on earth is **Asia.**

Comment: I have never heard a mountain described as “long”, just a mountain range. I don’t think you’re completely off-base, but I do think you are over-generalizing. Big doesn’t mean wide - a “big” man can be either tall, or wide, or both for example.

Comment: yeah but we do use word "high" in such contexts. "high" is a metric for length and not at all for area anyway.